# Show box with incoming call number using callKit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I have an app which will show box with incoming caller number when incoming call received. Is it possible in iOS using Objective C language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe CallKit gives you the incoming call number since that could lead to privacy issues. As far as I'm aware, all CallKit APIs deal with taking a number from you and processing it but not providing you with any numbers from incoming calls etc.

Comment: That wasn't me - I mean the point decrease. I think somebody else did that and you would want to ask them about that. But would appreciate a "correct answer" if my answer satisfies you.